# How to work with offline google maps in android

Tags: android

in android application i am displaying Google maps. suppose if any network problem comes, i need to display offline google map. how to do this one. please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your code. What did u try??

Comment: if any network problem is there at that time i am unable to download the Google map. So is there any chance to get the offline Map when network condition in bad position.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check your internet connection in that case...

try with following code ..

```
if (Constants.isInternetOn(Poll.this) == false
                            || Constants.wifiConnectivity(Poll.this) == false) {
                        Constants.showAlert("No network connection",
                                "Alert!!!", getParent());
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply i need to show offline google map, when i am unable to load Google map

Comment: when ever you need to show a google map all time you need a internet connection ...